# Count the no of LI then add class to parent UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul class="taglib-ratings thumbs">
<li id="qezr_yourRating">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="rating rate-up "></a>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="taglib-ratings thumbs">
<li id="qezr_yourRating">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="rating rate-up "></a>
</li>
<li id="qezr_yourRating">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="rating rate-up "></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply the class to the UL on base of the Count of the Inner LIs.

Like if it has two LI then the class should be like two-thumbs
Like if it has one LI then the class should be like one-thumbs

I am trying this JS but not working it returns 2

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var countLi = $(".taglib-ratings > li").size();
alert(countLi);
if(countLi == 2)
{
  $(this).parent('.taglib-ratings').addClass('2-col');
  alert ('this ul has 2 li');
}
else if(countLi == 1)
{
  $(this).parent('.taglib-ratings').addClass('2-col');
   alert ('this ul has 1 li');
}
else if(countLi > 2)
{
  alert ('this ul has'+ countLi +' li');
}
});
```

Here is the JSbin link to the same.

http://jsbin.com/ofeda/edit

Comment: that jsbin is poping up "3" then "this ul has3 li"

Comment: Most browsers do not support class names that start with a number. It should probably be something like `col-2` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(".taglib-ratings").each(function(){

    if ($(this).children('li').size() == 2 )
    {
      $(this).addClass('Two');
       $(this).append('Two');
      }
    else if ($(this).children('li').size() == 1 )

        {
      $(this).addClass('one');
       $(this).append('One');
      }

  });
```

http://jsbin.com/ofeda/2

[LINK TO UPDATED JSbin](http://jsbin.com/ofeda/2)

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not complement your explanation... you saying you want x-thumbs, but the code extract is doing nothing like that?

Do you mean something like this instead?

```
$('ul.tablib-ratings').addClass(function () {
    return 'thumbs-' + $(this).children('li').size();
});
```

You're getting "thumbs-1" instead of "one-thumbs" here, because it's a 1,000,000 times easier, and as noticed in the comments, many browsers won't appreciate `1-thumbs`

<s>You're getting "1-thumbs" instead of "one-thumbs" here, because it's a 1,000,000 times easier :P</s>

Comment: Most browsers do not support class names that start with a number. It should probably be something like `thumbs-1` instead.

Comment: Humm... `thumbs-1` it is then :P

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty obvious bug in this, if I'm understanding what you're trying to do:

```
else if(countLi == 1)
{
 $(this).parent('.taglib-ratings').addClass('2-col'); // shouldn't this be 1-col?
 alert('this ul has 1 li');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.tablib-ratings').each(function(i,ul){
    li_amount = $(ul).find('li').length;
    $(ul).addClass(li_amount+"-thumbs");
});
```

This will check all `ul.tablib-ratings` and will add classes according to `li` amounts. However the class names will be like `1-thumbs`, `2-thumbs` etc... but you can easily map the numbers to their written versions with a few lines of more code.

Hope it helps, 
Sinan.

Comment: The second parameter of `each` is the DOM Element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: @matt thanks, you're right edited accordingly... But this one works definitely...

Answer (score 0):

You are counting the total number of `li`s nested within tags with the class `taglib-ratings`.  Instead you need to loop through each `ul` with that class, **then** count the number of `li`s within that particular `ul`